# Gitlab6.0 and Apache2

Tags: apache2, ubuntu-12.04, gitlab

please how to set Github 6.0 with Apache2?

Gitlab is installed according to the original instructions

Adjustment in Unicorn.rb

```
    ...
    #listen "/home/git/gitlab/tmp/sockets/gitlab.socket", :backlog => 64
    #listen "127.0.0.1:8080", :tcp_nopush => true
    listen "127.0.0.1:8080"
    ...
```

My Apache2 conf is :

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName git.domain.com

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/gitlab_error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/gitlab_access.log combined

        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
        <Location />
            ProxyPassReverse /
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
        </Location>
    </VirtualHost>
```

Bud i get :

```
    The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
    The proxy server could not handle the request GET /users/sign_in.

    Reason: Error reading from remote server
```

Thank you

Comment: I solved this problem. I had the unicorn.rb timeout set to 700. Then the problem stopped.

Answer (score 1):

In case this helps anyone else;

I had this same problem, but it was a lack of disk space in my case. I deleted some large backups and restarted apache with `service httpd restart` and my gitlab came back.