# Installed gitlab-omnibus 8.16 on debian vps - now how do I reach it?

Tags: linux, nginx, gitlab

Really sorry to ask such a dumb question here, it's been 10y since I configured anything on a webserver.

- I have a vserver with debian and the usual control panel stuff on it.
- I installed gitlab-omnibus 8.16, all services seem to be running on shell
- entering the IP displays the contents from standard debian apache webroot var/www with the control panels and everything, those are working

As I guess gitlab uses nginx, it should be independent from apache, so sites-available etc. won't have any effect. What do I have to configure?

Comment: Use sudo `systemctl stop apache2` and `sudo systemctl disable apache2`, then restart gitlab and use ip at port 80.

Comment: Thanks, now at least I see some gitlab. But it's still only the 404 page. even though all components seem to be running: un: gitlab-workhorse: (pid 9311) 317s; run: log: (pid 9899) 41036s
run: logrotate: (pid 9321) 317s; run: log: (pid 9919) 41027s
run: nginx: (pid 9327) 316s; run: log: (pid 9909) 41034s
run: postgresql: (pid 9338) 316s; run: log: (pid 9745) 41115s
run: redis: (pid 9346) 315s; run: log: (pid 9658) 41121s
run: sidekiq: (pid 9353) 312s; run: log: (pid 9889) 41042s
run: unicorn: (pid 9369) 311s; run: log: (pid 9858) 41044s

Comment: wait up to 5 mins if you just restarted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
sudo systemctl stop apache2
```

and

```
sudo systemctl disable apache2
```

Make sure gitlab is using nginx in `gitlab.rb`

Then restart gitlab

```
sudo gitlab-ctl restart
```

Now use ip at port 80.

Comment: Thanks so much! It works. What's missing: Styling (CSS and images), plus it's very slow. Is there a path to configure for CSS?

Comment: I updated gitlab.rb Config to use Nginx, now everything works fine - thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

> As I guess gitlab uses nginx, it should be independent from apache, so
>   sites-available etc. won't have any effect. What do I have to
>   configure?

Gitlab is bundled with nginx but you can disable it. Then Gitlab may be used with Apache HTTP server. It depends on your preference. Example configuration for Gitlab with Apache:
[Configure gitlab with apache2 (or nginx + apache2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28243357/configure-gitlab-with-apache2-or-nginx-apache2)